# Showing axes in bitmap plot in R and scaling bitmap plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am trying add axes to the bitmap plot in R. But its not showing those axes. I am using OS X 10.10 with R v3.3.0

```
set.seed(0)

#Sample matrix
bitmap<-matrix(rnorm(150000,mean=1:500),nrow = 300, ncol = 500)

image(bitmap,col = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,"Greys"), axes=FALSE, 
  useRaster = TRUE)

axis(1,at = seq(from=1000,to = 10000,length.out = 19), 
  labels = seq(from=1000,to = 10000,length.out = 19))

axis(2,at = seq(from=0,to = 100,length.out = 11),
  labels = seq(from=0,to = 100,length.out = 11))
```

1. How to show these required axes with required ranges in R ?
2. How to specify the size of the plotted bitmap in R, either in terms of pixels or in some length unit ?
3. How can I scale bitmap's width and height independently ?
4. Is there any other R package which will allow me addressing these parameters in a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image()` scales both axes to 1. You just need to adjust your `at=` values

```
axis(1,at = seq(from=1000,to = 10000,length.out = 19)/10000, 
  labels = seq(from=1000,to = 10000,length.out = 19))

axis(2,at = seq(from=0,to = 100,length.out = 11)/100,
  labels = seq(from=0,to = 100,length.out = 11))
```

The size of the rendered image is based on your current graphics device. You cannot explicitly control the size of the drawing area in pixels, just the overall plot size (with axes and everything). Graphics in R tend to grow and shrink depending on window size. You can fix the aspect ratio if you like with `asp=1` in the `plot()` call.

If you need pixel-level control, you might want to use some other program for plotting.

Comment: Thanks ! Your reply has answered my questions. I was not aware that *at* would range from 0 to 1.